# Active Record: Can I create a polymorphic-like association without actual polymorphism?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, associations

I was not sure how to word the question (edits welcome), but here is my question: Say I am adding a `Transporters` structure to existing `People` tables that high-level should act like:

- There are many `People`
- A `Person` can have a couple different types of `Transporters`, ie. `Transporter::Skateboard`, `Transporter::Car`, etc.

  - Each `Transporter` will probably have two useful columns:

    - the foreign key `person_id`
    - a value column (which will be used to calculate 'quality' in the class) (ie. `model` for `Transporter::Car` or `wheels` for `Transported::Skateboard`)
  - There will likely only ever be 3-5 types of `Transporters`
- The only was I plan to use these `Transporter` models are:

  - SQL analysis
  - Grabbing a list of `People` based on the 'quality' of their transporter (which is based on its `value` column, see below)

Structure:

```
class Person < MainRecord
  has_many :transporters
end

module Transporter
  class Car < MainRecord

    def quality
      if car.model = 'Honda' # This is made up, heh
        return 'high_quality'
      else
        return 'low_quality'
      end
    end

  end
end

module Transporter
  class Skateboard < MainRecord

    def quality
      if skateboard.wheels = '4'
        return 'high_quality'
      else
        return 'low_quality'
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Main concerns:

- Analysis ease
- Query efficiency (grabbing `People` with 'quality' transporters in the backend without too much of a hassle)

I could use polymorphism, but given that these tables will mostly be used for analysis, the intermediary polymorphic table could be an annoying extra step. I also thought of having one transporter table with multiple columns but I don't think that's the best way.

Is there a way to set up 'polymorphism' without the extra intermediary table? Or is there a nicer solution for this setup?

Comment: "there likely won't be Car or Skateboard-specific methods" - what you have shown appears to violate this statement. "Query efficiency" there is no way to make this efficient unless `quality` is a persisted attribute of the "Transporter" objects. What is shown here is that `quality` is a deterministic method call (which cannot be queried in the traditional SQL sense). At first glance it seems a combination of STI and a join table would be the best fit for this paradigm

Comment: @engineersmnky That's a good point, I'll update this. Thank you!